# Enumeration all possible matrices with constraints

Tags: c++, python, recursion, matrix, enumeration

I'm attempting to enumerate all possible matrices of size `r` by `r` with a few constraints.

1. Row and column sums must be in non-ascending order.
2. Starting from the top left element down the main diagonal, each row and column subset from that entry must be made up of combinations with replacements from 0 to the value in that upper left entry (inclusive).
3. The row and column sums must all be less than or equal to a predetermined n value.
4. The main diagonal must be in non-ascending order.

**Important note is that I need every combination to be store somewhere, or if written in c++, to be ran through another few functions after finding them**

`r` and `n` are values that range from 2 to say 100.

I've tried a recursive way to do this, along with an iterative, but keep getting hung up on keeping track column and row sums, along with all the data in a manageable sense.

I have attached my most recent attempt (which is far from completed), but may give you an idea of what is going on.

The function `first_section():` builds row zero and column zero correctly, but other than that I don't have anything successful.

I need more than a push to get this going, the logic is a pain in the butt, and is swallowing me whole. I need to have this written in either python or C++.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
global r
global n 
r = 4
n = 8
global myarray
myarray = np.zeros((r,r))
global arraysums
arraysums = np.zeros((r,2))

def first_section():
    bigData = []
    myarray = np.zeros((r,r))
    arraysums = np.zeros((r,2))
    for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        myarray[0,0] = i
        stuff = []
        stuff = list(combinations_with_replacement(range(i),r-1))
        for j in range(len(stuff)):
            myarray[0,1:] = list(reversed(stuff[j]))
            arraysums[0,0] = sum(myarray[0,:])
            for k in range(len(stuff)):
                myarray[1:,0] = list(reversed(stuff[k]))
                arraysums[0,1] = sum(myarray[:,0])
                if arraysums.max() > n:
                    break
                bigData.append(np.hstack((myarray[0,:],myarray[1:,0])))
                if printing: print 'myarray \n%s' %(myarray)
    return bigData

def one_more_section(bigData,index):
    newData = []
    for item in bigData:
        if printing: print 'item = %s' %(item)
        upperbound = int(item[index-1])    # will need to have logic worked out
        if printing: print 'upperbound = %s' % (upperbound)
        for i in reversed(range(1,upperbound+1)):
            myarray[index,index] = i
            stuff = []
            stuff = list(combinations_with_replacement(range(i),r-1))
            for j in range(len(stuff)):
                myarray[index,index+1:] = list(reversed(stuff[j]))
                arraysums[index,0] = sum(myarray[index,:])
                for k in range(len(stuff)):
                    myarray[index+1:,index] = list(reversed(stuff[k]))
                    arraysums[index,1] = sum(myarray[:,index])
                    if arraysums.max() > n:
                        break
                    if printing: print 'index = %s' %(index)
                    newData.append(np.hstack((myarray[index,index:],myarray[index+1:,index])))
                    if printing: print 'myarray \n%s' %(myarray)
    return newData

bigData = first_section()
bigData = one_more_section(bigData,1)
```

A possible matrix could look like this:
r = 4, n >= 6

```
|3 2 0 0| = 5
|3 2 0 0| = 5
|0 0 2 1| = 3
|0 0 0 1| = 1
 6 4 2 2
```

Comment: when you say "non-ascending order" do you mean that at least one must not be in ascending order or that none of them could be?  eg. you could say that {0,1,2,3,4,5,7,6} is in non-ascending order since 6<7, or you could say it is in ascending order since 2>1.

Comment: I mean non-ascending in the meaning that I can have 2,2,0
or something like 2,1,0 but not 0,2,2. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in numpy and python 2.7. Note that all the rows and columns are in non-increasing order, because you only specified that they should be combinations with replacement, and not their sortedness (and generating combinations is the simplest with sorted lists).

The code could be optimized somewhat by keeping row and column sums around as arguments instead of recomputing them.

```
import numpy as np

r = 2 #matrix dimension
maxs = 5 #maximum sum of row/column

def generate(r, maxs):
    # We create an extra row and column for the starting "dummy" values. 
    # Filling in the matrix becomes much simpler when we do not have to treat cells with
    # one or two zero indices in special way. Thus, we start iteration from the
    # (1, 1) index. 

    m = np.zeros((r + 1, r + 1), dtype = np.int32)
    m[0] = m[:,0] = maxs + 1

    def go(n, i, j):
        # If we completely filled the matrix, yield a copy of the non-dummy parts.
        if (i, j) == (r, r):
            yield m[1:, 1:].copy()
            return

        # We compute the next indices in row major order (the choice is arbitrary).
        (i2, j2) = (i + 1, 1) if j == r else (i, j + 1)

        # Computing the maximum possible value for the current cell.
        max_val = min(
            maxs - m[i, 1:].sum(), 
            maxs - m[1:, j].sum(),
            m[i, j-1], 
            m[i-1, j])

        for n2 in xrange(max_val, -1, -1):
            m[i, j] = n2
            for matrix in go(n2, i2, j2):
                yield matrix

    return go(maxs, 1, 1) #note that this is a generator object

# testing 
for matrix in generate(r, maxs):
    print
    print matrix
```

If you'd like to have all the valid permutations in the rows and columns, this code below should work.

```
def generate(r, maxs):
    m = np.zeros((r + 1, r + 1), dtype = np.int32)
    rows = [0]*(r+1) # We avoid recomputing row/col sums on each cell.
    cols = [0]*(r+1)
    rows[0] = cols[0] = m[0, 0] = maxs

    def go(i, j):
        if (i, j) == (r, r):
            yield m[1:, 1:].copy()
            return

        (i2, j2) = (i + 1, 1) if j == r else (i, j + 1)

        max_val = min(rows[i-1] - rows[i], cols[j-1] - cols[j])

        if i == j: 
            max_val = min(max_val, m[i-1, j-1])
        if (i, j) != (1, 1):
            max_val = min(max_val, m[1, 1])

        for n in xrange(max_val, -1, -1):
            m[i, j] = n
            rows[i] += n
            cols[j] += n 
            for matrix in go(i2, j2):
                yield matrix
            rows[i] -= n
            cols[j] -= n 

    return go(1, 1)
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I had no expectations of such a complete answer so quickly. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: I removed the min check on the diagonal element, as I realized it's superfluous after the row/col checks.

Comment: I do have one question/comment though. This does not completely exhaust possibilities, as the diagonal elements seem to be constrained by the elements above and to the left. And it should only be constrained by the top left element, if that makes sense.
[[6,4,2],[3,5,0][*,*,*]] will never happen, because that 5 in element [1,1] would be constrained by the 3 and 4 above and to the left of it.

Comment: Well, in your second constraint you required that all rows and columns should be combinations with replacement. I interpreted that as our needing to include only all combinations and not all permutations; this implies that we make a choice (and a bit arbitrary of that) to skip some of them. But getting all the permutations should be also quite easy. I think I'll do an edit in the answer for that.

Comment: ... But I just realized that up until now I completely ignored that row and col sums must be also in non-ascending order. It seems to be the case though in the code in my answer. It somewhat complicates the permutation-generating version.

Comment: Correct, I have since (I believe), figured out the answer by just adapting what you wrote, but if you have an idea feel free to submit it. I am very happy with what you gave to work with